# Why is this not False? (SameQ,Equal, Set)

Tags: evaluation, expression-test

How can we understand why *Mathematica* does not evaluate this expression to `False`?

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}} == 0
```

Comment: Some functions will make the necessary mathematical analysis: `Reduce[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}} == 0]` returns `False`.  So does `Resolve[..]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Answer

Your example uses `Equal` (`==`) and it's returned not-evaluated because both sides are not identical and not raw data, therefore they constitute an equality expression. It would return `False` if you used `SameQ` instead of `Equal`.

### `SameQ`,`Equal`, `Set`

[`SameQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html)`[lhs,rhs]` or `lhs === rhs` yields `True` if the expression `lhs` is identical to `rhs`, and will always be `False` otherwise.

[`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html)`[lhs,rhs]` is used to represent a symbolic equation, to be manipulated using functions like `Solve`. It will yield `True` for identical expressions or `False` if determined to be unequal by comparisons between numbers or other raw data, such as strings. But most importantly it will not always evaluate to `True` or `False`, otherwise you wouldn't be able to use expression such as `x^2==4`.

Also consider [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) (`=`), `Set[lhs,rhs]` or `lhs=rhs` evaluates `rhs` and assigns the result to be the value of the symbol `lhs`.

I suggest you read [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/10397).

Answer (score 3):

What does `{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}} == 0` mean in a mathematical sense? Comparing matrices to scalars is strange. To make a comparison like this, *Mathematica* needs some set of rules that could possibly reduce the expression to something that's an identity, or recognize the impossibility. I guess it has no such set for a matrix to scalar comparison. However:

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 2, 1}} == {{0}}
(* False *)
```

Comment: absolutely relevant point. my mistake was to assume data comparisons (so to speak) would work with the same syntax as mathematical (logical) comparisons