# Why does the Euler identity not seem to be recognized in Mathematica?

Tags: trigonometry

Why does the following equation:

```
E^(I*theta) === Cos[theta] + I*Sin[theta]
```

yield false, in terms of Euler's Identity?

Comment: Try `Simplify[E^(I*theta) == Cos[theta] + I*Sin[theta]]`. Note `SameQ` (`===`) means identical expressions (as in, identical code). It does not test mathematical equivalence.  `Equal` (`==`) can do that, but it is reluctant to try all but the simplest transformation. Hence, you often have to use `Simplify` to test mathematical equality.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8796/evaluating-an-if-condition-to-yield-true-false, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201808/why-is-this-not-false-sameq-equal-set . Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115303/testing-equivalence-of-analytical-expressions-like-x2-x-xx-1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing equivalence of analytical expressions like $x^2 -x == x(x-1)$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115303/testing-equivalence-of-analytical-expressions-like-x2-x-xx-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Simplify[E^(I*theta) == Cos[theta] + I*Sin[theta]]
(* True *)
```

`===` is **structural** identity, not mathematical. `==` is mathematical equality. *Mathematica* only does simple reductions automatically: this is a case where you need to ask it to try a little harder than usual.